# Android runtime exception thrown when setting camera with null surface texture

Tags: android, camera

I developed a background camera, but I have a strange thing. My apps can work fine in these devices: Samsung Note2 android: 4.1.2 , 4.4.2, LG G3 android 4.4.2, Asus android 4.4.2. However, this fail in these devices, such as REDMI android:4.2.2, Samsung S6: 5.1, Samsung note3: 4.3, Sony Xperia: 4.4.4, Sony Z3: 4.4.4. I would like know the reason and solution. Thanks all.

MY MANIFEST:
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"

My logcat(REDMI,SONY Xperia,Samsung S6, Samsung Note3):

> -LOGCAT OF REDMI android 4.2.2: 
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2889):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
>         E/AndroidRuntime( 4105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>         E/AndroidRuntime( 4105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service
>         com.video.MyService: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to     camera service
>
> -UPDATED LOGCAT of SONY Xperia android 5.0.2
>   I/Process ( 4492): Sending signal. PID: 4492 SIG: 9
>   W/ResourceType( 4857): Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
>   V/MyActivity( 4857): Camera found
>   W/CameraBase( 4857): Camera service died!
>   W/CameraBase( 4857): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
>   E/video   ( 4857): failed to open Camera
>   W/System.err( 4857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:520)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:361)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at com.video.MyService.safeCameraOpen(MyService.java:151)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at com.video.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:92)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2785)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:149)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
>   W/System.err( 4857):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 4857): Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4857): Process: com.video, PID: 4857
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 4857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.video.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewTexture(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)' on a >null object reference
>
> -LOGCAT Samsung Note3 android 4.3
>   E/MediaRecorder(31528): start failed: -19
>   W/dalvikvm(31528): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417fc898)
>   --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31528): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2241
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31528): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
>
> LOGCAT Samsung S6
>   D/OpenGLRenderer(27352): Render dirty regions requested: true
>   D/PhoneWindow(27352): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
>   D/PhoneWindow(27352): *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
>   D/libEGL  (27352): loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
>   I/OpenGLRenderer(27352): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   I/OpenGLRenderer(27352): HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x7f73cbd1a0 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 1866187440 
>   D/OpenGLRenderer(27352): Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192
>   D/OpenGLRenderer(27352): Enabling debug mode 0
>   D/mali_winsys(27352): new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
>   I/LoadedApk(27352): getClassLoader :dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file 
>   E/SELinux (27352): [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>   D/TimaKeyStoreProvider(27352): TimaSignature is unavailable
>   D/ActivityThread(27352): Added TimaKeyStore provider
>   --------- beginning of system
>   D/LoadedApk(27352): getResources for android.app.ActivityThread@fde5c5f forcing ? false needsResourceUpdate ?false
>   I/InjectionManager(27352): Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
>   D/AssetManager(27352): addAssetPath path =/data/app/com.video-1/base.apkmapset is 0
>   D/AssetManager(27352): addAssetPath path =/data/app/com.video-1/base.apk, mapOffset =0
>   D/LoadedApk(27352): getResources for android.app.ActivityThread@fde5c5f forcing ? false needsResourceUpdate ?false
>   I/LoadedApk(27352): getClassLoader :null
>   I/InjectionManager(27352): Inside getClassLibPath caller 
>   I/LoadedApk(27352): classLibPath :, mActivityThread.mCoreFeatureClassLoader :null
>   D/InjectionManager(27352): InjectionManager
>   I/Choreographer(27352): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   I/LoadedApk(27352): getClassLoader :dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.video-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]]
>   E/BufferQueueProducer(27352): [unnamed-27352-0] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=8 undequeued=0)
>   E/BufferQueueProducer(27352): [unnamed-27352-0] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=8 undequeued=0)
>   E/BufferQueueProducer(27352): [unnamed-27352-0] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=7 undequeued=1)
>   E/BufferQueueProducer(27352): [unnamed-27352-0] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=7 undequeued=1)
>   E/BufferQueueProducer(27352): [unnamed-27352-0] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued >buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=7 undequeued=1)

here is my code:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
   private  Camera mcamera;

   @SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) public void     
   onCreate() {

    mcamera=Camera.open();

                try {
                    mcamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            mcamera.startPreview();

      public void capture(){

                mcamera.takePicture(null, null,null,mPicture);
            }

                 PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback(){

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera mcamera) {
                        (...)
                };
(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your manifest contains all the necessary privileges? When I had a similar issue, the solution was that the task had to be loaded asynchronously. If this is the case, you would need an `AsyncTask` to either open your camera or to capture a picture or for both.

I hope this input helps.

Comment: MY MANIFEST: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but why can Samsung NOTE2 works?

Comment: The android versions are different: android 4.1 versus android 4.2. That's why I think, that you will have to implement either an AsyncTask, a Service or some other feature that android changed between 4.1 and 4.2. Good luck!

Comment: YES, I did use service .

Comment: Well, in my case, I needed an AsyncTask to process the data I captured. Therefore, I can't tell you exactly what you need. But it definitely is something similar: a feature that was not requested for Android 4.1, but is for Android 4.2 and higher. You might find more info by googling "API 16 vs API 17" or maybe here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Comment: I would like know whether  mcamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));  cause the problem ?

Comment: If you debug it, you will be able to confirm that yourself. We don't have all the code, so we can't test it for you. As this part of the code is in a try-catch block, you could simply also write `Toast.makeText(...).show();` in the catch block and if it's displayed, then try caught an error.

Comment: Hi allhksar. Have you found the bug? I just thought about two things that could be related to it: 1.) Application Life Cycle (see: [App Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) ) and 2.) memory allocation for your app might be limited. (see: [Memory in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) )

Comment: I think this is not quite related to the issues you've mentioned.I find the major problem is this code- mcamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0)); Because , Sony Z3, Redmi will auto shut down the apps if i even put this sentence in main activity oncreate(), not in service. But samsung note2 and asus wont have this problem. Therefore i think the investigation should focus on the null surface texture (0). How do we solve or find another solution if the phones do not support the null surface texture(0) when background service camera recording or taking picture functions are needed.

Comment: What is the exception you receive? Because if the issue is `new SurfaceTexture(0)`, then you should get a Surface.OutOfResourcesException. (As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) ) I will be abroad for 10 days, therefore I suggest you change the title of your question: it is very broad, so not many people are interested in it.

Comment: Thanks for your concern on my question. What is your suggestion about my title? Android camera with nulk surface texture?

Comment: i have tested fail in samsung s6 android 5.1 , success in lg g3 andrpid 4.4.2

Comment: As a title for your question I would use something like "Android runtime exception thrown when setting camera with null surface texture" or so. The more details you write, the more people will directly see, if they can help. Well, the testing result seem pretty random. But I still firmly believe that you probably have just a detail that is incorrect. (Like position of the code or missing memory allocation.) Anyway, it would help to know where (on which line) the exception is thrown. I will check the thread again in 10 days, when I get back. Good luck!

Comment: guicor , glad to meet you, bro. Would you mind to leave your contact ?  Maybe there will be chance to investigate other topics together.